# Is it possible to know, how many pen drive connected with pc for one day?

Tags: usb, file-sharing

Because, I shared files but I don't remember how many person.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look in your logfiles, new entries are added to `/var/log/syslog` each time a USB key is plugged.

You can open `/var/log/syslog` as root with a text editor (`sudo gedit /var/log/syslog`), or:

```
sudo grep "Attached.*disk" /var/log/syslog
```

To count:

```
sudo grep "Attached.*disk" /var/log/syslog | wc -l
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean you want to know how many times a flash drive was installed in a usb port on a particular computer.

Start a terminal with Alt+Ctrl+T and run:

```
tail -f /var/log/syslog
```

Now insert your thumb drive. You should see a line display like:

```
Aug 12 11:44:05 gruber-precise-laptop kernel: [ 1386.413812] scsi 8:0:0:0: Direct-Access     TOSHIBA  TransMemory      PMAP PQ: 0 ANSI: 0 CCS
```

Now you can cancel the `tail -f` command with CTRL+C, and enter:

```
grep "Toshiba  TransMemory" /var/log/syslog*
```

and see all the times the flash drive was installed recently.

You can pick something else in the string as well:

```
grep "0:0:0: Direct-Access" /var/log/syslog*
```

but this will pick up things like your disk drive and any card readers at boot time, so you will have to look at the name to tell which is which.

```
On my system:

grep "0:0:0: Direct-Access" /var/log/syslog* | egrep -v "ATA|Multi-Card" | wc -l
```

finds the discovery of all direct access devices, eliminates the ones that I get at boot (and maybe wake up) for my hard disk and multicard reader, and counts them.

On my system sudo isn't necessary for any of these commands.